# OrderBy: Could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0

After ef core 3.0 breaking change i am unable to order columns directly from sql server.

```
return query.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(pageSize.Value * (pageNumber.Value - 1)).Take(pageSize.Value)
                         .ToList();
```

After updating to .net core 3.0, i am getting an error Unable to evaluate.

Comment: There is **no** EF Core 3.0 at this time. What we have is EF Core 3.0 **preview**, and like any preview (beta) software, it's expected to have issues and is not supposed to be used in production code.

Comment: try storing `pageSize.Value` and `pageNumber.Value` into variables and use the variables in `Skip` and `Take` methods

Comment: @Kahbazi I am having issue with ordering not paging

Answer (score 0):

You could add `AsEnumerable()` right before ordering if handling process was possible on the client side.

```cs
return query.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(pageSize.Value * (pageNumber.Value - 1))
    .Take(pageSize.Value).ToList();
```